# How do I Query Polymorphic Comments when commentables can belong to another commentable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, comments, polymorphism

So I'm trying to do a relatively advanced query on a polymorphic model. I have the following models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_stakeholders, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :features, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :iterations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class ProjectStakeholder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Iteration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :created_by, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

I'm trying to find the current_user's comments for a particular project (project.comments, project.features.comments, project.iterations.comments, project.project_stakeholder.comments) and sort them in created_at descending order.

The best I have come up with is:

```
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def all_comments_for_user(user)
    Comment.where(:created_by_id => user.id).select { |c| c.commentable.attributes.has_key?('project_id') }.select { |c| c.commentable.project == self } | comments.where(:created_by_id => user)
  end
end
```

But this doesn't address the descending create_at sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def all_comments_for_user(user)
    Comment.where(:created_by_id => user.id).order('created_at DESC').select { |c| c.commentable.attributes.has_key?('project_id') }.select { |c| c.commentable.project == self } | comments.where(:created_by_id => user)
  end
end
```

Does this work ? I just added order('created_at DESC')

Comment: Boo... it doesn't order the project.comments that are 'piped' in to the first array.

Comment: I could not understand. Can you explain what happened ? and also can you explain what you are trying to do with the | comments.where(:created_by_id => user) at the last.

Comment: Comments can also belong to Projects as well. That's picking those up and adding them to the array of comments that belong to commentables that belong to the project in question.